# .Net Core XUnit Issues on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, nuget, xunit

I'm working with .Net Core 5.0.408 on Debian Linux and have a basic project setup as

`/UnitTest/src/UnitTest.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

`/UnitTest/src/UnitTest.cs`

```
using System;

namespace UnitTestNs {
    class UnitTest {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("UnitTest");
        }
    }
}
```

Just as bare bones as possible and when doing a regular build everything is fine

```
dotnet clean ./src
dotnet add ./src package Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
dotnet build ./src --output ./cmp
```

Nice clean build

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  UnitTest -> /UnitTest/cmp/UnitTest.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.58
```

But adding the XUnit packages seems to break it

```
dotnet clean ./src
dotnet add ./src package Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
dotnet add ./src package xunit
dotnet add ./src package xunit.Runner.VisualStudio
dotnet build ./src --output ./cmp
```

Build full of warnings like this

```
/UnitTest/src/UnitTest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.5.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

And this

```
CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer Xunit.Analyzers.AssertCollectionContainsShouldNotUseBoolCheck cannot be created from /home/devuser/.nuget/packages/xunit.analyzers/1.2.0/analyzers/dotnet/cs/xunit.analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.. [/UnitTest/src/UnitTest.csproj]
```

Setting up XUnit in projects like this used to work but I'm not sure if something in NuGet has become scrambled or if something in the package has actually changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a package that is not compatible with net5 https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio#supportedframeworks-body-tab

You can try to use the older version [2.4.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio/2.4.5#supportedframeworks-body-tab).

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I was misunderstanding the .Net versions, the XUnit site says it supports .NET Framework 4.6.2+ but also .NET 6+. I don't know what the difference is between .NET Framework and .NET 6 but I just upgraded to .NET 7 and seems fine now